# Google Cloud Storage - Restrict access to files to a specific domain

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, hosting

I am using Google Cloud Storage for my WordPress website and I would like to know if there is a way to restrict access to my files so that only my domain will be able to access them. I tried Google Search but I couldn't find anything. Could you please tell me if I can do that and how?

Comment: will you please add few line of code or error if any.

Comment: No errors yet as I don't even know where to start

Comment: So how would you identify its restricted?

Comment: I would recomend you to read some documentation, specific https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin , i´m looking for the same, but It does not work for now, I´ll see if I can solve it, you may find this error too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124777/cross-origin-not-working-i-get-anonymous-caller-does-not-have-storage-objects-g

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear for which purpose you wish to use Cloud Storage for your website.

You can look at [this article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/) with respect to Cloud Storage access control. I would recommend looking at [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam) since I believe your want to allow domain access to all the files in Cloud Storage.

In general, if you want to host your WordPress website on Google Cloud, [several options are available](https://cloud.google.com/wordpress/):

- WordPress Single Instance using Cloud Launcher
- WordPress on Kubernetes Engine
- WordPress on App Engine

If you want to integrate WordPress with Google Cloud products, like Cloud Storage, there are plugins available from the [Google Cloud Platform GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/wordpress-plugins).