# cross-origin not working I get "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to"

Tags: google-app-engine, cross-domain, google-cloud-storage

In a bucket you can change cross policy https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin
I followed this steps:

In gsutil: 
First I removed the read permisions from allUsers that I configured at first

```
gsutil iam ch -d allUsers gs:/myBucketName
```

I removed it because even if I configured the json to serve only on localhost:8080, it serves content from other ports. 
Then I configure with gsutil as pointed out here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors
this json options:

```
[{ "origin":["http://localhost:8080"],
"responseHeader":["Content-Type"],
"method":["GET"],
"maxAgeSeconds":0
}]
```

In gsutil:

```
 gsutil cors set cor.json gs://myBucketName
```

After that, I´m using a simple html and a local server that only have this content:

```html
<html>
<body>
<img src="linkfrombyObject">
</body>
</html>
```

But I when my broser try to fetch the image, It gets and xml that says:"Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get 
[image]

[image]
any idea what could be wrong?
[image: comand line]

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as the pictures.

Comment: Could you provide some information what you want to accomplish? And why you wouldn't use the credentials? 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication

Comment: I want the resources from my bucket only work on my domain, that´s why I don´t make the bucket public. I tried to make it public with the same configuration as the json part and cloud storage serves the content in all ports. I followed intructions from https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors,  setting preflight maxAgeSeconds to 0 because as I said, I only want resources to be serve on my domain. By the way I don´t want my users to log in with google accounts. sorry if I don´t answer fast enough, right now I have not internet at home.

Comment: The link you provide won´t work for me because I don´t want my users to log in with their google accounts, if I would do it, it would be like trying to login to facebook and then I would log in to with  google, It would be pretty anoying for my users to log in twice. That´s why I have chosen cross origin.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not gonna work out with CORS. If you don't want to expose your files to public and reach them without authentication, you should use signed URLs: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: I think that won't work neighter, I will be serving video content, I just don't want any user even having the  video url by opening the development console, could download the video, I know that is not all that posible but I want  to make it harder to do it. Providing a signed url, users would continue with just the url, download the video,  that's why the only option I saw use full in this case, was setting cors

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what exactly you are saying. You want to prevent your users from downloading the videos? Could you explain what the idea is? Where the application serving this videos will be running? It would be nice if you could provide me an use case scenario.

Comment: I want my users only watch the videos if they are on my site, normaly a user with curiosity could just inspect  the video url and easily download the video by entering it on  his browser, in order to prevent that behavior I though setting cross origin was the solution, by the way sorry for my english I'm spanish speaker